# Get the index for certain row not working except for zero

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have a dataframe with the index and a column named 0
[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ect8E.png)

When I search for the index value of all the rows equal to '0' with
`df.index[df[0] == 0].tolist()`
It is working no problem
[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9fmB.png)

When I search for the index value of a row equal to a specific value such as '0.000376' with `df.index[df[0] == 0.000376].tolist()`. The output gives me nothing eventhough this value does exist in the data set.
[image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFSi1.png)

Must be veeery basic but yeah I've been stuck on this for 2 days lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to floating point approximation, use:

```
import numpy as np
df.index[np.isclose(df[0], 0.000376)].tolist()
```